# DataTables not redraw my data

Tags: javascript, c#, datatables

I have a problem with _fnReDraw in DataTables, I am using  DataTables and that receive data of the my controller C#, my controller return json with Exception or sucess, but my DataTables ReDraw only a first situation.

For exemplo, if firs moment my controller return Exception my Datatables Redraw only exception, but se first moment return sucess my dataTables ReDraw only sucess.

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")',
  data: JSON.stringify(json),
  datatype: "JSON",
  async: true,
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  success: function(result) {
    eval($('#MydatatTables').dataTable())._fnDraw();
  },
});
```

Comment: [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Code : $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")',
                        data: JSON.stringify(json),
                        datatype: "JSON",
                        async: true,
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        success: function (result) {                                             eval($('#MydatatTables').dataTable())._fnDraw();                          
                        },
                    });

Comment: @Cassiano - you should edit the code into the question, not post it as a comment.  Have edited your post.

Comment: `eval($('#MydatatTables').dataTable())._fnDraw();` looks highliy suspiscious,  `$('#MydatatTables').dataTable().fnDraw()` is the way you should use `fnDraw()` (no eval and no underscore) - but you should consider upgrading to dataTables 1.10.

Answer (score 0):

As is said in the comments, there doesn't seem to be any reason for you `eval()`.

It is hard to understand exactly what you are saying in your question, but are you receiving table data back from your ajax call? If so, you need to repopulate the table with the new data before calling a table refresh. Using the *new* [datatables api](http://datatables.net/reference/api)), you would do something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")',
  data: JSON.stringify(json),
  datatype: "JSON",
  async: true,
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  success: function(result) {
    var dtApi = $('#MydataTables').DataTable();
    dtApi.clear(); //clear old data from table
    dtApi.rows.add(result);
    dtApi.draw();
  }
});
```

If you do not need to update the data, you can just leave out the `clear` and `rows.add`. Hope this helps.